# Setup of terrarium for an early life experiment

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, virology

I'm building a terrarium in which an early life environment will be simulated. Over multiple years a few experiments with different starting molecules/atoms will be held in it. The selected materials will be manipulated through grinding against each other, being mixed, slow temperature change and radical temperature change. Different starting materials with different manipulations will lead to different new molecules being formed. The more diverse and complex the molecules I end up with are, the liklier it is I'm getting closer to simulating the start of life on a planet. I expect to find ways of recognizing certain molecules through how they 'behave'. The thing I'm most interested in, would be to map out what types of changes in environment are required to get over hurdles in which diversity or complexity start to stagnate.

The way I imagine I could set it up:

- Get a very big, cleaned transparent plastic bag that's flexible enough for hands to be able to grip objects through it.
- Put the bag around the terrarium, the selected prepackaged molecules, gas bottles, a bottle of alcohol and some tools.
- Close the bag and install a small pump on its surface.
- Pump as much air out of the bag as possible.
- Release some gas from the bottles inside the bag to make working easier. (Else the bag sticks to the open terrarium-box)
- Cover everything inside the bag with alcohol.
- Pump all the gas out again and release new gas from the bottles.
- Clean the insides and the lid of the terrarium with towels.
- Open each bag of molecules (salts, carbon, water, etc.) and drop the contents into the terrarium.
- Seal the terrarium very well.

Are there any better ways of sterilizing an environment to a point where no molecules formed through evolution on earth are inside of it?

E.G. heating it for a long time, drenching it in a base/acid...

Comment: I don't want to discourage you from at-home experimentation, but this isn't going to work. Everything that goes into the chamber needs to be *sterile*, not just clean. Bacterial spores, for example, can be extremely resistant to many forms of cleaning and sterilization - some can survive high doses of radiation, others the vacuum of space. Creating clean rooms is a whole industry in and of itself, and involves everything from the air circulation systems to the water to gasses to the materials of each surface, plus a *ton* of experience and lots of validation to make sure it actually is clean.

Comment: Aside from the extremely difficult mechanics of setting everything up and keeping it sterile, what are your endpoints going to be? You say you're working with "molecules" - how are you going to tell if your experiment is successful? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See a somewhat related question on Space.SE involving the difficulty in ensuring spacecraft do not accidentally bring organisms to other places: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54293/is-there-any-demonstrated-or-even-proposed-technology-that-can-sterilize-a-space

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for taking the time. I'll elaborate at the top of the post and make the question at the end of the post more specific.

Comment: @Bryan Very interesting. Thanks you!

Comment: I suggest you investigate chemical means of cleaning - strong acids (3-5 M nitric, 5 M HCl) neutralized with strong base (NaOH) should work. Note that we don't actually know the conditions in the early earth, but a number of "biological"-like molecules are found in the spectra of stars and in lunar dirt, meteorites etc.

Comment: this may save you a lot of trouble, this is not an easy experiment to duplicate in a small school lab but it is doable. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mp9l3LhPLgE